# Nonblocking queue of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue, python-multithreading

I want to create simple queue of threads.

THREADS WILL START WITH POST REQUEST

I created simple example without requests. I tried to join threads, but it doesn't work as i want.

```
def a():
    print('start a')
    sleep(5)
    print('end a')


def b():
    print('start b')
    sleep(5)
    print('end b')


t = Thread(target=a)
t.start()
t.join()
print('test1')
t = Thread(target=b)
t.start()
t.join()
print('test2')
```

Result of code:

```
start a
end a
test1
start b
end b
test2
```

Expectation:

```
start a
test1
end a
start b
test2
end b
```

I know i can print('test1') before join, but when i use post request thread can start in time of printing ('test1')

```
t.start()
print('test1') <- here comes post request
               t1.start()
               print('test2')
               t1.join()
t.join()
```

In this case threads will run parallel

Comment: Do you always want the *first* thread to finish before the second is started? does the completion order matter?

Comment: @wwii Order of threads it is not so important. I am using api which limits number of requests per second, so the most important thing is to avoid running threads parallel.

Comment: Why are you using threads if you want to "avoid running threads parallel" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `timeout` argument to `join()`, this will block the calling thread maximal `timeout` seconds. 'Maximal' because the thread can terminate earlier. If you don't pass a timeout, it will block until the thread finishes. So what you would have to do in your example is join the thread twice, the first time with a timeout which allows printing `test1`.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def a():
    print('start a')
    sleep(5)
    print('end a')


def b():
    print('start b')
    sleep(5)
    print('end b')


t = Thread(target=a)
t.start()
t.join(0.1)
print('test1')
t.join()

t = Thread(target=b)
t.start()
t.join(0.1)
print('test2')
t.join()
```

Output:

```
start a
test1
end a
start b
test2
end b
```

Apart from that, I'm in doubt this is a good approach if your concern is just limiting requests per second. You could reuse your threads instead of recreating them for every request this would spare you the creation overhead. You could use a ThreadPool and emit a request task into the pool with your specified heartbeat.

```
import logging
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def make_request(*args):
    logger.debug(f'making request number {args[0]}')
    sleep(5)


def init_logging(log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    fmt = '[%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(threadName)s' \
          ' %(funcName)s()] --- %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=log_level)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_THREADS = 5
    N_REQUESTS = 10

    arguments = [*zip(range(N_REQUESTS))]  # [(0,), (1,), (2,) ...]

    init_logging()
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    with ThreadPool(N_THREADS) as pool:
        for args in arguments:
            pool.apply_async(make_request, args=args)
            sleep(1)  # heartbeat
```

Example Output:

```
[2018-09-09 03:17:06,303 DEBUG    Thread-1 make_request()] --- making request number 0
[2018-09-09 03:17:07,304 DEBUG    Thread-2 make_request()] --- making request number 1
[2018-09-09 03:17:08,306 DEBUG    Thread-3 make_request()] --- making request number 2
[2018-09-09 03:17:09,307 DEBUG    Thread-4 make_request()] --- making request number 3
[2018-09-09 03:17:10,308 DEBUG    Thread-5 make_request()] --- making request number 4
[2018-09-09 03:17:11,309 DEBUG    Thread-1 make_request()] --- making request number 5
[2018-09-09 03:17:12,310 DEBUG    Thread-2 make_request()] --- making request number 6
[2018-09-09 03:17:13,311 DEBUG    Thread-3 make_request()] --- making request number 7
[2018-09-09 03:17:14,312 DEBUG    Thread-4 make_request()] --- making request number 8
[2018-09-09 03:17:15,313 DEBUG    Thread-5 make_request()] --- making request number 9

Process finished with exit code 0
```